# What is difference between ATAG and cmdline?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

As far as I know ATAG and cmdline are both way to passing kernel parameter from boot loader to kernel.
However I can't understand what differences between them.

When I port Device drivers, I use ATAG and cmdline for passing kernel parameters from boot loader to Kernel.
I searched them, and I still can't understand between them.
As far as I know ATAG means kernel tagged list used in ARM architecture, and Flattened device tree functions pretty much like ATAG.
I probably can say that I got some clue to understand ATAG.
However cmdline so confuses.

Is ATAG like Device tree? And is cmdline a tool for adding property to ATAG?

Comment: ATAG is a protocol used to pass bootloader parameters including cmdline to the kernel.

Comment: Does it mean that cmdline is a component included in ATAG?

Comment: See [here](http://www.simtec.co.uk/products/SWLINUX/files/booting_article.html)

Comment: Note **including** in my comment. And see the given link in another comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATAG and DeviceTree are two methods to pass parameters to kernel.
Command Line is one of the parameters.

Take LK code(Little Kernel: app/aboot/aboot.c) below as example, in function boot_linux(),
depending on definition of DEVICE_TREE, final_cmdline either passed to kernel via device tree or via atags.

```
    void boot_linux(void *kernel, unsigned *tags,
        const char *cmdline, unsigned machtype,
        void *ramdisk, unsigned ramdisk_size)
{
...
#if DEVICE_TREE
    dprintf(INFO, "Updating device tree: start\n");

    /* Update the Device Tree */
    ret = update_device_tree((void *)tags,(const char *)final_cmdline, ramdisk, ramdisk_size);
    if(ret)
    {
        dprintf(CRITICAL, "ERROR: Updating Device Tree Failed \n");
        ASSERT(0);
    }
    dprintf(INFO, "Updating device tree: done\n");
#else
    /* Generating the Atags */
    generate_atags(tags, final_cmdline, ramdisk, ramdisk_size);
#endif
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
It helps me a lot understand concepts.